# angular js data now showing in front end

Tags: angularjs

the data is showing in the log but its now showing in my page.i wanted to load the data . what is the problem?

```
function AppController($scope, TestFactory) {
  /* console.log("AppController is now available.");*/
  $scope.testdata= [];
  TestFactory.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.testdata = response.data;
    console.log("Data:", $scope.testdata);
  })
}


<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="event in testdata">
              <div class="now-viewport">
                <div class="event-image">

                </div>
                <div class="event-placeholder">
                  <div class="event-title">{{ event.message}}</div>
                  <div class="event-details">


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ion-slide-page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code below

```
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="event in testdata.message">
   <div class="now-viewport">
      <div class="event-image">
          <div class="event-placeholder">
             <div class="event-title">{{event}}</div>
             <div class="event-details"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </ion-slide-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an **`object`** where **`message`** is an array of **strings**, try as follows,

```
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="event in testdata.message">
   <div class="now-viewport">
      <div class="event-image">
          <div class="event-placeholder">
             <div class="event-title">{{event}}</div>
             <div class="event-details"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </ion-slide-page>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Greatly Appreciated your help.

Comment: i have checked it sir

Comment: Why did you remove the answer